# Radioactivity of elements

Tags: atomic-physics, radioactivity

I know that when number of protons is high, the nucleus of atoms become unstable due to repulsive force and is radioactive. But why is that the nucleus also becomes unstable when there are too many neutrons?

Comment: That question is not even close to my question

Comment: It happened that I read both.  The moderators are right. The two Qs are basically the same.

Comment: What i mean is why does there have to be balance between no. of protons and neutrons. If there is high no. of neutrons then why would it be radioactive

Comment: Ok I see now what you mean. As for neutron being neutron and as such doing nothing .... Consider that neutron as free particle is unstable. Then is matter of nuclear physics . It makes sense to me that protons and neutron glue and stabilise themselves within a certain limit. Radioactivity presumes something stable enough (metastable) for the decay to occur.

Comment: Can you explain why a free neutron is unstable?

Comment: Not really. But it has a lifetime of 12 minutes so it is. However is not the main point of your question. Also for that I have not answer if not that from a certain point adding neutrons does not stabilise overcrowded nuclei. I mentioned the short lifetime of neutrons to say that themselves do not bring any stabilisation factor. It is rather their interaction with protons that does it. The rest is at quark level and I have no idea. Empirical data are however a good base.

Comment: It would be better to ask why protons and neutrons glue together. The repulsion base story is not enough.  I am afraid that would be a very hard question even here.